# Inactive VTE after cancel in Geany

Tags: geany

I execute python scripts in the VTE using the Execute command from the build menu. When I stop a process in the VTE using Ctrl-C, the "Terminal" title in the tab becomes red and the terminal is inactive. Launching an Execution does not work. I need to press enter in the terminal to make the terminal active again.

Reproducible example:

- Launch a process in the VTE, e.g. "top"
- Ctrl-C to cancel
- Then try to execute a file using the Execute command from the build menu. It should do nothing.

Is this a bug ?
(I am on Xubuntu 18.04)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a feature.
Whenever it seems to Geany that the terminal may contain any input data, automatic command execution, like the Execute command from the build menu, is disabled to prevent executing whatever is left on the terminal command line.

Imagine you accidentally pasted something like "rm -rf ~ &&", don't notice it and then let Geany execute your script. The previously pasted command will be executed as well and you loose all your data.
It is technically not possible to clearly say whether there is no input data left on the command line. To protect the user, Geany marks the VTE as dirty in such cases.

I see it's seems inconvenient in the described scenario but as said, here we better need to be safe.

Another way to mark the VTE as clean is by pressing Ctrl-C a second time.

Comment: OK thanks ! I wasn't sure if it was a bug or a functionality. I see the benefits in terms of security. So now I use an external terminal (xterm) to run my code.